# SVG mask destroys SVG drop-shadow (inclusive fiddle)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, mask

I made a 
-SVG drop shadow 
and a
-SVG mask

The mask is all white, so there should not be an influence to what we see.

What is wrong? Here is the fiddle comparing both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/LMH3X/

```
// JUST FILTER ----> it works
svg.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", "someJpeg.jpeg")
.attr("...", "...")
.style("filter","url(#drop-shadow)");

// FILTER AND MASK ----> it does not work
svg.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", "someJpeg.jpeg")
.attr("...", "...")
.style("filter","url(#drop-shadow)") 
.attr("mask","url(#mask1)");
```

I appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`maskUnits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/maskUnits) attribute set to `"userSpaceOnUse"`, since this will use your `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` as the values.

I'm not an SVG expert, so I can't fully explain why it works. But if you don't specify it, it defaults to using the bounding box of the element.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMH3X/1/) showing it and below is the relevant code:

```
var mask = defs.append('mask')
        .attr('id', 'mask1')
        .attr('maskUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .append('rect')  
        .attr({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 1000,
            height:1000,
            fill: 'white'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. Solved the problem completely!

Comment: The default for masks is to use objectBoundingBox units - http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#Masking

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/render.html#Elements explains why. Filters apply first, masks second. Setting `maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse'` just means you set a very large mask on the element (defaults being `[x,y,width,height] = [-10%, -10%, 120%, 120%]` of the viewport) - which can have a serious impact on performance. Note that the provided attributes in the example in this answer are for the rect inside the mask, they don't define the size of the mask.